# How does angular2 distinguish between different <ng-template>?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am writing a table component, usually the contents of the table are fixed, but some columns may require component users to create a column template, I am prepared to pass the  to pass the custom column template, but I encountered a problem, I did not know which columns I needed to customize when I passed the column data.

Now I have simplified the code as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
            <div *ngIf="!item.value">
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.ref" [ngOutletContext]="{}"></ng-template>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="item.value">{{item.value}}</div>
        </ng-container>
    `
})
export class DatatableComponent{
    @Input() data: object[];
    @ContentChildren(TemplateRef) get refs(val: TemplateRef<any>) {
        // How to map refs here to map above
    }
}

// use it:
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <example [data]="data">
            <ng-template name="test1">test1</ng-template>
            <ng-template name="test2">test2</ng-template>
        </example>
    `
})
export class DatatableComponent{
    // I know that you can get references here
    // But this hard code is too cumbersome,
    // I was wondering if there was any other better way
    public data: object[] = [
        {name: 'test1'},
        {name: 'test2'},
        {name: 'test3', value: 'test3'}
    ]
}
```